# Nested ssh tunnels

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I want to connect to the port of a server through another server.

```
mypc --> host 1 port 1431--> final host port 8080
```

But to connect to the first server, I have to send my credentials, and to connect to the second I have to send a private key. So I try this:

```
ssh -L8080:IP2:8080 -i private-key user2@IP2 -R 8080:localhost:8080 user1@host1 -L1431:host1:1431
```

Where `IP2` is a private IP.

But I'm not having success. I'm begginer in this domain, so I don't understand very well how to do it. I read some tutorials, but It's not working.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to map 'final-host, port 8080' ? To be publicly available as 'host-1, port 1431' ? To be available on localhost at port 8080? By private IP - you mean it's on a network of non-public IPs behind publicly available host-1 ?

Comment: 1. I want to map the port 8080 in my local pc, 2. The port 1431 is publicly available and the 8080 too. 3. Yes, is a non-public IP behind a publicly available host-1.

Comment: In that case you shouldn't even need to login into final host - host1 can already access final-host's port 8080. Use this: `ssh -N -L 8080:final-host-ip:8080 user1@host1`. Why even specify port 1431 ? Is that the port on which SSH runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I use this according to the comment of @Marek Rost and it works.

```
ssh user@host1 -L8080:host2:8080 -i private-key
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ssh -J user1@host1:1431 -i private-key -p 8080 user2@IP2
```

or if you have older OpenSSH client:

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -p 1431 -i private-key user1@host1" -p 8080 user2@IP2
```

Comment: I don't know why, but ssh tell me that `-J` is not a valid option.

Comment: Because you have old openssh. For that reason I wrote also the alternative for old OpenSSH clients.